# Collect log files from FTP into Logstash/Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ftp, logstash

I am investigated the Elastic stack for collecting logs files. As I understand, Elasticsearch is used for storage and indexing, and Logstash for parsing them. There is also Filebeat that can send the files to the Logstash server.

But it seems like this entire stack assumes that you have root access to the server that is producing the logs. In my case, I don't have root access, but I have FTP access to the files. I looked at various input plugins for Logstash, but couldn't find something suitable.

Is there a component of the Elastic system that can help with this setup, without requiring me to write (error-prone) custom code?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use exec input plugin with curl. Something like:

```
exec {
    codec => plain { }
    command => "curl ftp://server/logs.log"
    interval => 3000}
}
```